# Recrete animated "tab" buttons from iOS Photos

Tags: swiftui

I want to recreate the animated buttons found in the Photos app and shown below. My goal is to use this type of buttons in a TabView(or something similar) instead of the default ones. Does these type of buttons exist in swiftUI? Or what is a good way to create these buttons?
[image]

I have written some stupid code to illustrate the problem, but it feels like the wrong approach.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                    .offset(x: CGFloat(selection * 100), y: 0)
                HStack {
                    Button("Tap Me") {
                        withAnimation {
                            selection = 0
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Tap Me") {
                        withAnimation {
                            selection = 1
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Tap Me") {
                        withAnimation {
                            selection = 2
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 300)
            }
            .padding()
        .background(.green)
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Probably a good candidate for `matchedGeometryEffect`

Comment: Well the closest one that SwiftUI offers is `Picker` with `.pickerStyle(.segmented)`. See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-segmented-control-and-read-values-from-it

Comment: The code you wrote is completely fine. Obviously it could be touched up to look like the iOS version, but then you'll have lots of customization available to you.